# List of changes for Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

This [list of changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html) for Android Marshmallow was very useful. Is there a similar list for Nougat? If so, how does one find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, Android N is still in the preview state, so the documentation for it is at a preview URL. The [Behavior Changes category](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html) is the closest match to the page that you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

As Android Nougat is still in preview state, check: [Android N for Developers](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html) sections which highlight of the new features for developers like:

- Multi-window Support
- Notification Enhancements
- Quick Path to App
- Install Doze on the Go...
- Vulkan API
- Quick Settings Tile API
- Virtual Files

Make sure to check out the [Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html) to learn about areas where platform changes may affect your apps.

You can also  download the [API Reference](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#docs-dl) for details on new APIs.

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks, both of those links are helpful!

Comment: Links need to be updated as pointing to Android O now. Correct links is [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is some behaviour changes mentioned in [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html):

To alleviate these issues, Android 7.0 applies the following optimizations:

- Apps targeting Android 7.0 do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
  broadcasts, even if they have manifest entries to request
  notification of these events. Apps that are running can still listen
  for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE on their main thread if they request
  notification with a BroadcastReceiver.
- Apps cannot send or receive ACTION_NEW_PICTURE or ACTION_NEW_VIDEO
  broadcasts. This optimization affects all apps, not only those
  targeting Android 7.0.